# How can i fix this redirect error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

imgslink.biz is my site when i upload any image and try to open it it give me 404 error imgslink.biz/img-53fc4f024b830.html . here is my .htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?imgslink\.biz/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ nohotlink.gif [L]
<Files ~ "\.(php|sql|php3|php4|phtml|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi)$">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Thanks

Comment: Open the webserver errorlog (usually /var/log/nginx/error.log or /var/log/apache2/error.log (depends on used webservice)).

Comment: can't find the error log

Comment: You should be able to find good examples of mod-rewrite directives doing what you want by [searching the tag for "hotlink"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmod-rewrite%5D+hotlink). Compare their code to yours and see what might be going wrong.

Comment: still getting this error

Comment: any one here who help me ?